# Consequence of Lemma: If G is abelian with exponent n, then $|G|\big\vert n^m$ for some $m\in N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Lemma: If G is abelian with exponent n, then $|G|\big\vert n^m$ for some $m\in N$.
Theorem to be proved: Suppose G is finite abelian and group of order m, let p be a prime number dividing m. Then G has a subgroup of order p. 
My question is how to see that from the lemma that there is an element $x\in G$ which has divisible by p? I only see that there is an element of order $p\times m$ which is the exponent of the |G|=$p\times m$.

Comment: your this line needs an edit-"how to see that from the lemma that there is an element $x$ $\in$ $G$ which has divisible by $p$?"

Comment: If you are saying which has 'order' divisible by $p$, then why do you need that. According to theorem you need to prove only that $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$. Actually it is also true for non abelian groups. and it is called Cauchy's theorem. If you have done group action there is a very nice proof based on it which covers both cases. It is also a corollary to Sylow's first theorem.

Answer (score 1):

From the lemma (and the fact that $p$ is prime) we can deduce that $p$ must divide the exponent of $G$.

To obtain a contradiction, suppose that $g^p=1$ implies that $g=e$, i.e., that there is no element of order $p$.  By what was said above, we may write $\exp (G)=pn$, so that for all $g\in G$, we have $1=g^{pn}=(g^n)^p$.  By assumption, it follows that $g^n=1$ for all $g$, but this is a contradiction as $n<\exp(G)$.  Hence, there must exist some element of order $p$ which generates a subgroup of order $p$.